# Exchange Web Services API Linking emails in a conversation?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'd like to be able to log a unique id from an email with a delivery receipt in a database that i can then use to link the delivery receipt email when it comes back from the recipient. I tried using the Thread-Index Internet Message Header, but I don't have access to the message headers when I initially send the email.

Is it possibe to 
1. create an email.
2. add a delivery receipt
3. use a unique id from that email and store it in a database
4. search for that unique id in the delivery receipt message when it arrives.

Comment: I believe Internet Headers are not available until email is sent. Have you thought of generating thread-index yourself as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278314/how-does-the-email-header-field-thread-index-work  ?

Comment: How would I generate them before the email is sent?

Comment: The stackoverflow question that I mentioned contains the link to MSDN article describing how Thread-Index is constructed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528174(v=exchg.10).aspx You can use it to predict what the value of Thread-Index is going to be and store it in your database. Just an idea. I do not know of any other way to get access to Thread-Index prior to sending an email.