# Add headers to outgoing smtp message that will exist in reply

Tags: email, smtp, email-headers

I need to create a correlation between an outgoing e-mail to a reply e-mail without changing the subject or body.

I've tried to add some headers to an SMTP outgoing mail:

```
var outgoingMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mail.Headers.Add("Tag","MyNewTag");
mail.Headers.Add("CorrelationID","MyNewCorrID");
```

Unfortunately, when replying to that email message - those headers are gone.

Is there any way to correlate between outgoing and incoming message without interfering subject or body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the headers you should probably use X-headers instead:

```
mail.Headers.Add("X-Tag","MyNewTag");
mail.Headers.Add("X-CorrelationID","MyNewCorrID");
```

To correlate between outgoing and incoming message without interfering subject or body, you could also check the `References:` header (only with reply, not with forward).

This header contains the `Message-ID`('s) of the originating messages:

```
References: <some-id@domain>
```

There is also the `In-Reply-To` header.

To add more information you could even customize the outgoing `Message-ID`.

Maybe the [Thread-Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278314/how-does-the-email-header-field-thread-index-work) header could be helpful too.

Comment: I used References and it works great. Even when forward a message.

Comment: @ohadinho Good to hear. Preserving references when forwarding might depend on the e-mail client though. PS, there is also the `In-Reply-To` header (added to the answer).

Comment: unfortunately, none of these solutions work when replying from gmail client. Any ideas?

Comment: @ohadinho If the client decides not to include/preserve any of these headers in a reply then there's not much that can be done about it I think. Doesn't gmail client at least preserve the `Thread-Index` header? Or are there any other headers in a reply from gmail? (I don't have gmail so I can't test this) - The only remaining option then would be to keep a local list with `from` and/or `to` and `subject` for example, but even then those fields could be changed when replying.